# visual designer for MOSS 2007 webparts in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-designer

How do I develop MOSS 2007 WebParts with a visual designer?  So far, I've only figured out how to put together these parts from the code behind... which has been a pain. Am I just overlooking some obvious option?  I'm pretty new to both SharePoint and ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to use the smartpart, you can just create an empty webpart and in the createchildcontrols add the usercontrol.
This blog post explains it, although they should mention that you should put your controls in the _controltemplates directory instead of the _layouts folder.
http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=95

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SmartPart for SharePoint](http://smartpart.codeplex.com/). It is an amazing web part that will help you do exactly what you need.

Comment: That looks pretty nice.  Is there an easy way to use the SharePoint properties in conjunction with an ASP control? I'd like to be able to put the same webpart on multiple pages, but each having custom settings. I new how to do that from the actual webpart... not so much with this paradigm